# Android : inApp purchase receipt validation (Part 2)

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app, receipt

I am implement **inApp** purchase in my application and add product as "**Manage Product**". After purchase I want to do **receipt validation**.For that I configure in Developer console like

**The Steps are**

1. Developer Console -> Settings -> API access
2. Create Server account
3. Google Developer console -> Add a credential in Service account and put it as JSON
4. After adding I got a file from developer console it contains

   ```
   {
     "type": "service_account",
     "project_id": "api-xxxxx-xxx",
     "private_key_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
     "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\ixxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
      "client_email": "test-in-app-receipt-validation@api-xxxxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
      "client_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
      "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
      "auth_provider_x509_cert_url":   "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
      "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/test-in-app-receipt-validation%40api-9129873511008807687-564452.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
      }
   ```

But I don't know how to do the next step.
How to use this file **Receipt validation**

After purchasing am getting the reponse as

```
{ 
 "orderId":"12999763169054705758.1371079406387615", 
 "packageName":"com.example.app",
 "productId":"exampleSku",
 "purchaseTime":1345678900000,
 "purchaseState":0,
 "developerPayload":"bGoa+V7g/yqDXvKRqq+JTFn4uQZbPiQJo4pf9RzJ",
 "purchaseToken":"rojeslcdyyiapnqcynkjyyjh"
}
```

Can anyone please help me how to handle the next step for Receipt validation for the make use of downloaded file that contain JSON value

Comment: how are you getting the response which included the purchase info? I am not aware how to call it in my app (java)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following up on your [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35127086/android-inapp-purchase-receipt-validation-google-play) now that I know you're using Java for your server side code, you will want to use the [Google API Client Library for Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/). I'm not comfortable with Java myself but the documentation is easy to follow.

First of, you need to authenticate, take a look at the [example code](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2#service_accounts) Google provides. You currently have a JWT (JSON Web Token) but you can keep to the example by instead downloading the `p12` certificate file from the same place on the Google API Dashboard.

Your authentication code should look something like this:

```
HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance()

GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(httpTransport)
  .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
  .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
  .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton(AndroidPublisherScopes.ANDROIDPUBLISHER))
  .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("key.p12"))
  .build();
```

Also don't forget to set your `SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL` and store the `key.p12` file somewhere accessible to your server.

If you're interested, this is the [docs AndroidPublisherScopes](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/androidpublisher/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/androidpublisher/AndroidPublisherScopes.html).

As I mentioned, my knowledge of Java is limited so please use your disregard any mistakes I have made.

Google have made some [code samples](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/libraries) available with downloads and links to GitHub repos. I suggest checking those out.

From here you can use the [AndroidPublisher.Purchases.Products.Get](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/androidpublisher/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/androidpublisher/AndroidPublisher.Purchases.Products.Get.html#AndroidPublisher.Purchases.Products.Get(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method to retrieve the details of a purchase. The docs list the signature as following:

```
AndroidPublisher.Purchases.Products.Get(java.lang.String packageName, java.lang.String productId, java.lang.String token)
```

For subscriptions use [AndroidPublisher.Purchases.Subscriptions.Get](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/androidpublisher/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/androidpublisher/AndroidPublisher.Purchases.Subscriptions.Get.html#AndroidPublisher.Purchases.Subscriptions.Get(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).

If you need more help, consider asking a question with the `java` and `google-api-java-client` tags.

Comment: Thank you very much Marc @Marc Greenstock