# Android in-app purchasing for multiple types of subscriptions for same type of product

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Here I'm implementing Google's in-app purchasing for multiple types of subscriptions i.e. `monthly` , `quarterly` , `half-yearly` and `yearly`. 
I created `SkewId` for each of subscription type not for managed or unmanaged. These  subscription packages will work for same type of work. But now I wanna know how I can know that the subscription days, subscribed packaged after payment?

I implemented code for managed type as:

```
 mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);
    // enable debug logging (for a production application, you should set
// this to false).
    mHelper.enableDebugLogging(true);
    mHelper.startSetup(new
                               IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
                                   public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
                                       if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                                           Log.d("TAG", "In-app Billing setup failed: " +
                                                   result);
                                       } else {
                                           Log.d("TAG", "In-app Billing is set up OK");
                                       }
                                   }
                               });
}
 IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener
        = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
    public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result,
                                      Purchase purchase) {
        if (result.isFailure()) {
            // Handle error
            Log.d("TAG", "We have gas. Consuming it.");
            remove_ads_btn_monthly.setEnabled(true);
            remove_ads_btn_quarterly.setEnabled(true);
            remove_ads_btn_halfyearly.setEnabled(true);
            remove_ads_btn_yearly.setEnabled(true);
            if (plan_duration != 1)
                toast = new CustomToast(RemoveAdsActivity.this, "You've already subscribed package of " + plan_duration + " months.");
            else
                toast = new CustomToast(RemoveAdsActivity.this, "You've already subscribed package of " + plan_duration + " month.");

            return;
        } else if (purchase.getSku().equals(SKU_MONTHLY)) {
            consumeItem();
            remove_ads_btn_monthly.setEnabled(false);
            remove_ads_btn_quarterly.setEnabled(false);
            remove_ads_btn_halfyearly.setEnabled(false);
            remove_ads_btn_yearly.setEnabled(false);
        } else if (purchase.getSku().equals(SKU_HALF_YEARLY)) {
            consumeItem();
            remove_ads_btn_monthly.setEnabled(false);
            remove_ads_btn_quarterly.setEnabled(false);
            remove_ads_btn_halfyearly.setEnabled(false);
            remove_ads_btn_yearly.setEnabled(false);
        } else if (purchase.getSku().equals(SKU_QUARTERLY)) {
            consumeItem();
            remove_ads_btn_monthly.setEnabled(false);
            remove_ads_btn_quarterly.setEnabled(false);
            remove_ads_btn_halfyearly.setEnabled(false);
            remove_ads_btn_yearly.setEnabled(false);
        } else if (purchase.getSku().equals(SKU_ANNUALY)) {
            consumeItem();
            remove_ads_btn_monthly.setEnabled(false);
            remove_ads_btn_quarterly.setEnabled(false);
            remove_ads_btn_halfyearly.setEnabled(false);
            remove_ads_btn_yearly.setEnabled(false);
        }

    }
};

public void consumeItem() {
    mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mReceivedInventoryListener);
}

IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mReceivedInventoryListener
        = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result,
                                         Inventory inventory) {

        Purchase gasMonthly = inventory.getPurchase(SKU_MONTHLY);
        Purchase gasYearly = inventory.getPurchase(SKU_ANNUALY);
        Purchase gasQuarterly = inventory.getPurchase(SKU_QUARTERLY);
        Purchase gasHalfYearly = inventory.getPurchase(SKU_HALF_YEARLY);
        if (gasMonthly != null) {
            mHelper.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase(SKU_MONTHLY), mConsumeFinishedListener);
            mSubscribedTo = true;
        } else if (gasYearly != null) {
            mHelper.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase(SKU_ANNUALY), mConsumeFinishedListener);
            mSubscribedTo = true;
        } else if (gasQuarterly != null) {
            mHelper.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase(SKU_QUARTERLY), mConsumeFinishedListener);
            mSubscribedTo = true;
        } else if (gasHalfYearly != null) {
            mHelper.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase(SKU_HALF_YEARLY), mConsumeFinishedListener);
            mSubscribedTo = true;
        } else {
            mSubscribedTo = false;
        }
    }
};
IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener mConsumeFinishedListener =
        new IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener() {
            public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase purchase,
                                          IabResult result) {

                if (result.isSuccess()) {
                    //API
                    remove_ads_btn_monthly.setEnabled(true);
                    remove_ads_btn_quarterly.setEnabled(true);
                    remove_ads_btn_halfyearly.setEnabled(true);
                    remove_ads_btn_yearly.setEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    // handle error
                }
            }
        };
```

Now, I wanna know how I can customize my code for payment of each type of subscription as shown in image. Each subscription should get active itself when time period gets over.

Thanks.

Comment: consumeAsync for subscription ? No way.You are not supposed to use. please read the documention. subscriptions are not consumable

Comment: I mentioned above that I implemented this for managed product.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options to store the time of purchase eitheron server(then validate it in your app with current time)  or using googleplay `androidpublisher` [api](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/products).

In the response you will get PurchasedTime.

```
{
  "kind": "androidpublisher#productPurchase",
  "purchaseTimeMillis": long,
  "purchaseState": integer,
  "consumptionState": integer,
  "developerPayload": string
}
```

[Android : inApp purchase receipt validation google play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35127086/android-inapp-purchase-receipt-validation-google-play)

[Android : inApp purchase receipt validation (Part 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35169960/android-inapp-purchase-receipt-validation-part-2?lq=1)

Other than that.. you need to check each skus on queryInventory(You are only consuming Monthly).

```
    IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
        public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {


            Purchase gasMonthly = inventory.getPurchase(SKU_MONTHLY);
            Purchase gasYearly = inventory.getPurchase(SKU_YEARLY);
            if (gasMonthly != null) {
               mHelper.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase(SKU_MONTHLY), mConsumeFinishedListener);
                    mSubscribedTo = true;
            } else if (gasYearly != null) {
               mHelper.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase(SKU_YEARLY), mConsumeFinishedListener);
                    mSubscribedTo = true;
            } else {

                    mSubscribedTo = false;
            }
```

Edited:

> how I can know that the subscription days, subscribed packaged after
>   payment?

you will get get the purchased sku item on mPurchaseFinishedListener /mGotInventoryListener, save it on sharedpreferences or on a server.

for days validation. you will get purchaseTime from purchase. purchase using `purchase.getPurchaseTime()` you have to either store it on your app locally or querying purchased sku to get the time everytime.

Comment: Can you please tell me that should I use your code only or I need some more things too?

Comment: It'll be long process for me. I just want to enable consume task whenever I want.