# Android app Subscription details expiry date

Tags: android, in-app-billing, subscription

How to get Subscription details like Expiry date and Active status etc. I have completed buying subscription flow using

```
mHelper.launchSubscriptionPurchaseFlow((Activity) mContext, RegistrationAcceptActivity.SKU_SUBSCRIBE, RegistrationAcceptActivity.RC_REQUEST,
                    mPurchaseFinishedListener, "");
```

Once the it executed successfully, I got

```
{"orderId":"GPA.1380-1270-1169-98789","packageName":"com.xxx","productId":"xxxx","purchaseTime":1458222969093,"purchaseState":0,"purchaseToken":"aaaabbbbccccddddeeeeasdfsadfasdfsadfxcvxcvxcvxcsdfasdafsadfsd","autoRenewing":true}
```

But still I am searching for how to get subscription detail whenever needed. Ex: I need to send the updated expiry date to my server while splash activity loading.

Some one suggested to use Google Developer console(V2) API. Some of the classes are deprecated like HTTPDefaultClient etc.

I am unable to conclude whether this is the right solution or I need to follow some other way to get subscription details.

Comment: you need to use Google Play Publisher API. please go through this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35127086/android-inapp-purchase-receipt-validation-google-play

Comment: @Damodaran I'm also looking same scenario. Are you got the solution?