# inapp purchases - How to update game currency server side

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, billing

Could someone please explain how i can update a players currency on my server after a player purchases game  currency via the google billing library?

There doesn't appear to be any information on querying ones own server to update game currencies after purchasing.

Any help/durection would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Have you tried anything yourself? Do you have a code that you can share?

Comment: Thanks, I've found what i was after.

Comment: receipt validation through the Google Play Developer API https://stackoverflow.com/a/35138885/8667855