# Google Play Inapp Receipt Validation - Correct Role?

Tags: android, android-pay, android-inapp-purchase

I've been following the following guide on setting up a Google API service account for receipt validation https://stackoverflow.com/a/35138885/8667855.

This tutorial advises selection of "View Financial Reports" as the service account role.

However roles appear to have changed since this was first post, and now appear as
[Updated Roles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JW41p.png)

Which role should I select to allow for receipt validations on a remote server?

Thank you.