# Service account doesn't show up in Google Play Console after creation

Tags: android, google-api, service-accounts, google-play-console, receipt-validation

From my Google Play console I linked a project. Then I created a service account. Still, when refreshing the console, it still says "There are no service accounts associated with your project."
Waited over 24 hours already. The purpose of all that is receipts validation.

Picture 1: a linked project:
[image]

Picture 2: service-account created:
[image]

Comment: How did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 148):

I had the same problem, I fixed it this way:

When you create a service account in step 2, you need to select a role to grant this service account some permissions, although it shows the step is optional, but for some cases, it's not. If you skip this step, the newly created service account will not show up at the Google Play Console API access page, and you will get this error message, `The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation` when you run your code.

[image]

Comment: Ok now it worked -> I used the role "owner" plus I granted my user full access to the service account. I'm not sure if both optional steps are require though...

Comment: Does it have to be a special role or will "viewer" be enough?

Comment: @awendt At first the role should fit your needs, then it's better there are no redundant permissions. Personally the viewer role is a good start.

Comment: If you're concerned about not giving the account too many privileges (the viewer role enables it to view anything on your Google Cloud project!), the role "Service Account User" should be sufficient

Comment: If you didn't specify `role` when creating `Service Account` You can still add the role later- at IAM -> "Add"

Comment: "Service Account User" role did the job. Thanks a lot

Comment: If you set the "Service Account User" role when creating the service account, then it's set at the project level and anyone with access to the service account can impersonate any other service account in your project. So instead set it within the service account itself (click the service account in the "Service Accounts" screen and add it in the Permissions tab). Then it only has permission to impersonate itself, which means it has no permissions.

Comment: Exactly, I confirm this solution. In my case I gave just read_only but this time in step 2.

Comment: This worked 9/28/2021. Thank you!

Comment: @LawrenceKesteloot Unfortunately, adding the "Service Account User" role at the service account level doesn't work.

Comment: It still works on 06/29/2023. Thanks. If I add the role after created, it doesn't work. So you guys should be adding the role during the create account process.

Comment: This works for me as of 27/09/2023. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 5):

You must enable the "Google Play Android Developer API" (one of Google Api & services) for your application to use it via credentials
Google supplies many API for developers can call them from their app.

Go to [this url](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/androidpublisher.googleapis.com) click on the blue `enable` button, let the progress spinner finish and redirect you, then it should appear as a dropdown option in the play store console.

Answer (score 2):

In my case:
Even if you have created a service account,
When you have already deleted the service account with the same name,
It appears to have been deleted from the IAM tab of Google Cloud Platform.
So it is assumed that it is not visible in the play console.

TODO:
Create a service account with a different name (I gave the owner permission in step2 when creating, Like Q Locker's answer.).
After creation, it was immediately exposed in the play console.

Comment: Nice. Yeah it seems Play Console will only list Service Accounts that have been created with the correct permissions. Adding them after creation won't work.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue because I selected a wrong project instead of the project for which the service account to be created. Please double check the project name in the drop-down at top of the page (after going to the link of `Google Cloud Platform`). By default the right project to be selected automatically. But if no project is selected beforehand and you are asked to select a project, then select the right project carefully. Otherwise the service account won't show up after completing the whole process.

Another thing to mention, although the project is supposed to be selected automatically, initially it didn't happen and I was given the available projects to select from. The project may appear in the recent projects, otherwise click the `SELECT PROJECT` link and find yourself.

Moreover when I additionally logged out and removed all the other Google accounts from the browser except the account which is used in `Google Play Console`. That time I was redirected to service account creation page with the correct project **selected** beforehand.

Comment: Log out all google accounts and log in with the developer account credentials did the work. I deleted previous service accounts that I had created and then I created again.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the project name on screen 1 and screen 2 are the same. In my case project name were different.

Screen 1: Main API Access page on Google Console

Screen 2: Google Cloud Platform page

[image: Main API Access page on Google Console]
[image: Google Cloud Platform page]