# Unable to link "Google Cloud Project" for API access within Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-play-console

I have an issue where an error is shown when I make an attempt to link my PlayStore to a Google Cloud Project. There are 2 options:

- Link existing project - the dropdown actually shows my cloud project in the dropdown to select.
- Create new project
  Selecting either one of those and clicking "Link Project" gives "An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again. (76F5052F)". And the spinner spins indefinitely.

[image]

I have tried different browsers and been doing that for a few days just to make sure its not some temporary issue.

I have also got "Google Play Android Developer API" enabled within Google Cloud "APIs & Services". Also it is successfully linked to a Firebase project if this has any difference.

I need to link the project to Google could project so that I could use "Google Play Developer API" to validate in app purchase receipts.

I have read through and tried the folowing with no success.

- [Service account doesn't show up in Google Play Console after creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50208046/service-account-doesnt-show-up-in-google-play-console-after-creation)

Any pointers/help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Konaras, I've experienced exactly the same problem for a couple of weeks. Even though the error shows up in Google Play, on every such attempt the "Google Play Console Developer" project is created in the Google Cloud, but for some reason, it couldn't be linked to Google Play.

I have contacted Google Play support multiple times about this problem, but got only  "clean your browser cache and try again or contact Google Cloud".

It seemed like a project owners/permissions issue (maybe something related to recently released from beta Google Play console?), so I insisted on raising the priority of the case and even pointed them to this question. After that, I haven't heard from Google Play support for several days, but today I see the API access started working.

Konaras, try again and update if it's resolved on your side.

Comment: Vtps, thanks for the reply!  Weirdly enough in my case no new projects have been created on GCP. However, I experienced similar issue when trying to deploy a solution (tomcat) from GCP market to VM. It would not allow me to do that but instead create a new project. But this is a different issue.
Now back to the original problem, I have also contacted support and raised issue with them, but heard nothing back. 
Only to notice today that API access now does work. With absolutely no changes from my end. The only logical conclusion is that it was indeed a problem on their end which is now fixed.

Comment: I think documentation is confusing:

```Google Play Developer APIs will only accept calls from your linked Google Cloud project. This should not be the same Google Cloud project used for API calls in your apps. A Google Cloud project can only be linked to one developer account.```

What I am trying to do is to link existing Firebase project (listed as "owner" in Cloud Console). However, instead I need to create single new project for "Google Play" API access? Many Firebase applications, many Android applications, and single new project for API access (since I don't have such project yet".

Answer (score 0):

An update for anyone who might end up here. According to the [Google Play Developer API Docs](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/getting_started), "You no longer need to link your developer account to a Google Cloud Project in order to access the Google Play Developer API.".

So, this step is not needed anymore.

[image: Link not needed anymore]

Answer (score -1):

Please check this page https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/getting_started

Go "**Under a service account**" section.

Follow all steps and please read carefully this:
"*Note that you should grant your service account access to the project in order for it to appear in Google Play Console.*"

When you create service, in step 2, (API ACCESS PAGE) you have to add a role (owner). (Check image below)

If you followed all steps correctly, now your project is linked in your Google Play Console.

[image]

Comment: triple-checked: I am "owner" of few projects in console.cloud.group.com, but "Link an existing Google Cloud project" in play.google.com lists nothing. Using the same account of course.

Comment: I think documentation is confusing:
```Google Play Developer APIs will only accept calls from your linked Google Cloud project. This should not be the same Google Cloud project used for API calls in your apps. A Google Cloud project can only be linked to one developer account.```

What I am trying to do is to link existing Firebase project (listed as "owner" in Cloud Console). However, instead I need to create single new project for "Google Play" API access? Many Firebase applications, many Android applications, and single new project for API access (since I don't have such project yet".

Comment: @FuadEfendi you need to enable Google Play Developer API (androidpublisher api) from Google cloud first

Answer (score -3):

Please check this page [1] where you will be able solve your doubts regarding Google Play Console.

Have a nice day!

---

[1] - https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer

Comment: Ruben M, thank you for taking time to post your suggestion. I can assure you that I have crawled multiple times as much documentation as I could find on the matter before posting my question here. A week later and documentation re-read I am still experiencing the same issue which prevents us from moving forward with development.