# Google Play Developer API - "The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation."

Tags: google-api, google-api-client

I have a Google dev console process with Google Play Developer API is enabled and the project is linked to Google Play project.
In Google Dev console project, created OAuth Client ID (web application) (I'm an owner of the project). Using "client_id" and "client_secret" to authenticate.
Tried to using google-api-client in Python, Google Developer API Playground to send request to list reviews of our apps but got error: "The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation."
Details as below:
Request:

```
GET /androidpublisher/v2/applications/<package_name>/reviews
```

Response:

```
"error": {
    "code": 401, 
    "message": "The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation.", 
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "androidpublisher", 
        "message": "The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation.", 
        "reason": "permissionDenied"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 229):

There is one important thing about receipt validation using Google Play Android Developer API:

If you added your in-app product **BEFORE** granting permission or linking to your service account, you must open "In-app products" and change something. You can for example edit the description of your product and save it. You should instantly get the permission then.

Comment: This is the key. Damn you, Google. Any Google developer API experience has been trash but this takes the cake.

Comment: This works for me. For addition, make some changes in **Grow -> Store presence -> Main store listing** or **Monetize -> products -> In-app products/Subscriptions** also take effect.

Comment: Editing the description didn't work for me, creating and activating a new product did though (even for validating receipts for the old product).

Comment: This solution still valid to July-2022, lol :))

Comment: yea, it worked..... I simply edit the available country and region, untoggle, save then toggle and save one country and then it worked instantly....wtf google

Comment: Worked for me too, just update details and plan country/Region.

Comment: thank you very much for the solution, I would have probably spent hours or days trying to figure this out

Comment: Editing the description doesn't work. Disabling and enabling an IAP does work.

Comment: I can not believe it but It works

Comment: I can not believe it but It works 2

Comment: I can not believe it, because I'm pretty sure I ran across this post a year ago and forgot this happens, but it works 3.

Comment: This indeed actually works still in 2023, kudos to you.

Comment: It works in Mar 7, 2023!. got the permission by editing the name of an In-app product. Please not that editing the description didn't worked for me.

Comment: Changing description did not work but changing the price and then reverting back worked.

Comment: Note also when you update the Service Account's permission, the product needs to be "updated" again. Changing the "Benefits" in the subscription product worked for me.

Comment: This actually worked, google needs to fix this or add some note about it because without this answer I could never solve it

Comment: THANK YOU! Stack Overflows is still better than ChatGPT for the really stupid things. :)

Comment: Someone give this man a hug!

Comment: No F-ing way! We've struggled with this for 14 days, manually validating people because the receipt validation didn't work after repeatedly setting it up from scratch (company reorganization and new account). Changed one letter in an in-app purchase description, and voila. Dear God, this is amateur on Google's part.

Comment: Thank God for StackOverflow.  I think probably 500 developer hours have been saved by this question and answer.  Good work @Wojciech Kulik we all owe you!

Comment: @user3413723  I'm glad I was able to help you all with this dumb behavior :). I can't believe that my answer is still valid after over 3 years. I guess Google is too busy collecting user data to fix anything 

Comment: Oh my god, I cannot believe this is what I was missing. Stuff like this is why developers work overtime, I wasted more than 8 hours on this.

Comment: September 2023 and this is STILL the answer that saved me. I just toggled the Allow Resubscribe option off and on and BINGO. I already knew Google was sloppy. This is a prime example.

Comment: October 2023 and this is STILL the answer that made it work. How annoying. I did the same as @John and just toggled the Allow Resubscribe option and then my service account could send requests. Stuff like this is indeed why developers work overtime.

Comment: December 2023 and still the case... After an application transfer we had to recreate quickly access with API credentials to Google Play Console and we lost 4 hours with this bug. Documentation from Google is so short : https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/getting_started Developers work overtime and their clients are losing money too.

Comment: January 2024 and still the case... However, in my case I had to fill the required and missing Data Safety details

Comment: This used up hours of my time... Thanks for this post!
ChatGPT didn't know this one. Lucky stackoverflow is still alive :').

Comment: None of the above is working for me :( I have subscriptions though, not in-app products.

Comment: Feb 2024, None of the above worked for me as well. I am trying to get the subscription data https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/{packageName}/purchases/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/tokens/{token}

Comment: Still working in 2024 !! Thumbs UP to you ,, and shame on GOOGLE !!

Comment: Wow thanks for this one - Feb 2024 and still working.  I had to futz around with more than just the description - I changed pricing one and then back and boom.  Probably some caching that's too aggressive.  Thanks google for sucking!

Comment: this till works in 2024, however you will have to change name of the in app product, changing description wont work.

Comment: Like @EricBloch, the only thing working for us was updating the pricing on an existing subscription. Changing the description, adding a new subscription,... none of these worked.

Answer (score 83):

## I looked everywhere on the internet and found somewhere that you might need to wait for at least 24 hours.

**Ensure you have done everything correctly as below.**

1. Go to https://console.cloud.google.com
2. Create a project (or select existing project)
3. Create a service account with role Pub/Sub Admin
4. Go to https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library and search for "Google Play Android Developer API"
5. Enable that API
6. Go to https://play.google.com/apps/publish
7. Go to Settings > Developer account > API Access
8. Link the project that you created in step 2
9. The service account will appear that you created in step 3
10. Grant access to it with Finance permission to the app in play console
11. **Very important:** Wait for at least 24 hours for changes to take effect.

Comment: "Create a service account with role Pub/Sub Admi" I don't see how to add that role? Is this still valid? I already created the service account and I am getting the error mentioned here.

Comment: @salyela When you create a service account, after clicking next you will need to choose the role to service account (this is optional but need to add to make it work). See this https://ibb.co/5RysC1B

Comment: @Bikram Hi, Is 'Finance Permission' enough for get subscription data? (or) Need to give full permission?

Comment: @DhineshYes That would be enough I guess.

Comment: This is gold! Thank you, worked like a charm. Otherwise I guess we would have to wait for 24hs

Comment: You don't have to wait for 24 hours though. For me, it worked as soon as l made the changes

Comment: Instead of "11. Very important: Wait for at least 24 hours for changes to take effect." you can create new subscription, then it will work imediately.

Answer (score 41):

If you followed all what @Bikram listed and you still facing the same error. Do this, create 'Managed product' temporary and then delete them. This way, sure you don't have to wait 24 hours.

It works for me.

Comment: This just literally saved me! I wish I could award this answer a bounty!

Comment: OMG. I did not believe this would work, but it did. Thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you! This works now on December 18, 2020.

Comment: That made the trick for me as well, thanks! :)

Comment: I have tried all the above answers, now I'm trying your answer can you please help me with that. I have subscription plans so I'm adding new subscription plan from Monetize>Products>Subscriptions .but I'm not able to delete the subscription plans.
Am i doing something wrong? My account has admin access but I'm not an owner.

Comment: Changing something in "Main store listing", such as your app title or description for the Play Store, also updates the permissions instantly rather than having to wait 24hrs+.

Comment: Changing app description updated permissions instantly.

Answer (score 23):

I faced a similar issue, the problem is in the settings we do in google developer project.

Refer to [create-play-service-credentials](https://docs.revenuecat.com/docs/creating-play-service-credentials) for settings. Use the same primary account with which you created your in-app products.

Make sure you remove the previous one.

Link to a Google Developer Project
Your Play Developer account needs to be linked to a Google Developer Project.

**1a. Open the Settings > Developer account menus and select API access**

[image: API-access]

**1b. Select Link to connect your Play account to a Google Developer Project**

[image: choose-project-link]

**1c. Agree to the terms and conditions**

[image: agree-terms-conditions]

**2. Create Service Account**
Next we need to create a service account. This is done from the Google API Console.

**2a. Select Create Service Account**

[image: create-service-account]

**2b. Create Service account key credentials**

[image: service-account]

**2c. Enter details for service account**

[image: enter-service-account-details]

**2d. Download your JSON credential:**
[image: json-credentials]

**3. Grant Access**

**3a. In Play Console, select Grant Access on the newly created service account**

[image: grant-access]

**3b. Grant the following permissions:**

[image: apply-permissions]

**After granting access, Google takes 24-48 hours to propagate all access rights for all API's, till that time you'll continue to get the same error.**

Comment: Do we first need to select add app to grant permission or not ? Here in 3b steps it is asking to Me to invite user on my service account email ? do we need to do that or we need to enter any valid gmail account email because when i go to grant access it shows me invite user ? Any help will be appreciated as stuck on this..

Comment: For granting permissions to user you need to add the email and then set role as Editor, Admin etc. For grant permissions to app, you need to add that app first.

Comment: But while i am granting permission it is taking email as service account id as last screen shot 3a in your answer so we should give it permission to that right ?

Comment: Thanks for taking the effort to add screenshots. Google's systems are so ass backward and broken it is hard to know exactly which screen(s) you should be on otherwise.

Comment: Yea, I have to spend like few days just to figure out this mess. We generally some generic errors with which sometimes it is difficult to find what could be wrong.

Comment: Adding the Financial permission to the service account did the trick (3b. Grant the following permissions)!  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 17):

**After adding a new user in the Google Play Console, Google needs up to 24 hours to propagate all access rights for all apis.**

I ran into the same issue, when I've tried to using the [oauth2 flow](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/authorization) to access the [Inapp purchases status api](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions). It's not official documented, but this [github comment](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/1382#issuecomment-466306678) helped me to figure this out.

Comment: I'd been suffered hard for a whole day before I found this answer. THANKS a lot!
This answer should be accepted as a right one!

Answer (score 8):

Wait up to 24h OR create/edit any **In-App product** to force permission update,it takes 1-2 minutes to update and no need to wait 24h.

Answer (score 6):

For someone who is facing this exact issue then the simple answer is to check the permissions to the service account which is linked in the Google Developer Console.

1.Open the Settings > Developer account menus and select API access
2.Choose the service account and check the permissions- **REMEMBER FINANCE PERMISSION IS MUST FOR THIS ACTION**

[image]

And after giving the permission update your subscription/package and make a new purchase then try again.

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 6):

For my scenario:

If you are using service account to verify purchase via Google Play Developer API. Ensure you also click the **View app information and download bulk reports (read only)** permission besides the **Financial data** permissions.

[image]

After edited the permissions, update the in-app products and subscription (eg. change the descriptions).

Then wait for around 30 mins, the permission error gone.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting below response when verifying purchase using service account to call purchase API.

**Status: 401, message: The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation.**

The reason was that I not included the service account credentials in Google Play console. **Settings -> Developer account -> API Access** are now not showing on the Google Play Console.

So below are the steps I perform after that to get response from Purchase API:

**1.**  In the Google Cloud Console go to Service Accounts and create.

[image: Step1]

**2.**  Assign the Role.

[image: Step 2]

**3.**  Go to the Users & Permissions page on the Google Play Console and Click Invite new users.

[image: Step 3]

**4.**  Put an email address for your service account in the email address field.

[image: Step 4]

**5.** Add an app to grant the permissions and then click on manage permissions.
[image: Step 5]

**6.**  Grant the necessary rights to perform actions and click Invite user.

To use the Google Play Billing APIs, you must grant the following permissions:

•    View financial data, orders, and cancellation survey responses

•    Manage orders and subscriptions

[image: Step 6]

**After these steps create or update the existing product/subscription name, country it will affect instantly without any delay. This is needed because you created product/subscription id before granting permissions.**

[Reference and more details](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/getting_started)

**Done**

Answer (score 2):

I used **service key** and created it in *Google APIs Credentials Cloud Platform*, and I had the same issue until I added my created *service key* to *Google Developer Console* with all access.

I understood that you already created credentials in *Google Developer Console*, but maybe my experience will help someone else

Comment: I finally found that my email using for authentication need to be also granted  permission on the Google play store project to use the API(s).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, "Settings > Developer account > API Access" has disappeared in Google Play Console now! Instead, follow @BitQuestions instructions on inviting the service account user (email address of the service account) and grant the financial data permissions as per @Shivam Yadav

Also, @ihsanberahim tip was great to avoid 24hr delay in permissions propagation.

Comment: Adding more to this
1) I had to wait more than 24 hours
2) The API access page is straight up missing, it shows up on search but clicking on does nothing

Heres what i did

1) Create service account, i ended up giving owner roles out of frustration, maybe service account user should be sufficient ( someone else can comment if so)
2) You service account should have an email in the details tab, Go to the users and permissions section in Play console and add that user and give the View financial data, and manage orders permissions,

now you service account should be good

Answer (score 0):

For me the reason i had this issue because I did not check the permission to
`Release to production, exclude devices and use app signing by Google Play` in Google Playstore console for the `service account` I created to manage app creation and management.

So check `Users and Permission` in the Google Play store console and check if the appropriate permission is checked.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately for me, I didn't find the answer anywhere. The error still appeared. My problem got resolved when I changed the scope to: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher. This gives the correct OAuth credentials. After changing the scope, I started using the "purchases.subscriptionsv2.get" method (url: [https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/{packageName}/purchases/subscriptionsv2/tokens/{token}?access_token=your_access_token](https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/%7BpackageName%7D/purchases/subscriptionsv2/tokens/%7Btoken%7D?access_token=your_access_token)) instead of purchases.subscriptions.get (url:[https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/{packageName}/purchases/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/tokens/{token}?access_token=your_access_token](https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/%7BpackageName%7D/purchases/subscriptions/%7BsubscriptionId%7D/tokens/%7Btoken%7D?access_token=your_access_token)) . It was somehow screwed up and now everything works! I hope I helped to someone

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still trying to find exactly where the permissions have to be set, once you already configured all the other things, you can reach that section following these steps:

1. log to https://play.google.com/console
2. click on "Users and permissions", then click on the email address that corresponds to the service account (or click on "Manage" to the right of it)
3. click on tab "Account permissions".

As explained from previous comments, you only need to check "View app information and download bulk reports (read only)" and "View financial data, orders and cancellation survery responses", even if that makes no sense at all. Then wait for some hours, because not always the permissions get refreshed, even after following all the other suggestions. In my case, I waited overnight.

Answer (score 0):

I was also struggling with the permissions issue. I went ahead a assigned app specific permission to the service account user:

[Click Manage link on the user and you will see the following section on the next page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9ksy.png)

[After selecting the app and clicking apply, you need to add the following permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwKzd.png)

I tested immediately after applying those permissions and it was not working. But came back next day and it was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Guys if your purchase API is giving error with `The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation.`

#### All you need to do is create a new in app product and wait for few minutes and hit the API again.

##### Here is the code for NodeJS:

```js
import { GoogleAuth } from "google-auth-library";

const client = new GoogleAuth({
  keyFile: "./sql-play-pk.json",
  scopes: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher",
});

const packageName = "com.SqlPlay";
const productId = "premium";

const token = "your purchase token";

const purchaseUrl = `https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/${packageName}/purchases/products/${productId}/tokens/${token}`;

const res = await client.request({
  url: purchaseUrl,
});

console.log(res.data);
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Go to Settings > Developer account > API Access

1. but the API access one click connect function is deprecated.
2. so we should add the service account address to <play store console, users-and-permissions>([https://play.google.com/console/u/0/developers/${your](https://play.google.com/console/u/0/developers/$%7Byour) project id}/users-and-permissions)
3. set account permission.

done

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone stumbles upon this question, based on the information in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76304392/23329373), it appears that Google has significantly altered the way service accounts access the Google Play Console. Notably, the "API Access" menu option seems to have been removed. During the billing setup, you might have noticed the requirement to grant permissions to your tester list, allowing them to make purchases while developing the in-app products feature. If you've followed all the steps correctly (which can be challenging, given the complexity and organization of Google's documentation), the service account email you created and added to the Google Play Console should also be included in your list of testers. You can find the License Testing section [here](https://play.google.com/console/u/0/developers/7614899048295285963/license-tester).

Answer (score 0):

For those that have been using the credentials without issues until a specific moment, and don't have access to the Play Developer Console, you must know that these keys expire. After re-enabling it, it will take some hours until it starts working again.

Answer (score 0):

In 2024: In My case it worked after adding the service account email in "Users and permissions" section of Google Play Console.
I have Subscriptions not the products.

Important note: that we need to wait at-least 24hrs after adding the user in Google play console

[image]

Answer (score -2):

It will automatically be fixed after 24 hrs, don't waster your time and energy with hacks, just wait and watch.