# "The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation.” - Google Play Developer API

Tags: android, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-client

I am having trouble calling the Google Play Developer API.

I have followed all steps listed on https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/authorization . This includes

1. Create Project and enabled **Google Play Android Developer API** (with my Google Play Console Account)
2. Link the project through Settings > Developer Account > API Access
3. Grant access to service account with finance permissions to the app through the Google Play Console.
4. Create **OAuth 2.0 Client Id**, **Client Secret**, and **Redirect URI** credentials.
5. Generate the **Refresh Token** and the **Access Token** by sending POST request.

Then, to call the purchases.subscriptions.get API, I used the following CURL command:

(https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.subscriptions/get)

```
curl -X GET "https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/{packageName}/purchases/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/tokens/{token}" -H "Authorization: Bearer {access_token}" -H "Accept: application/json" --compressed
```

However, I am receiving the following error:

```
"error": {
    "code": 401, 
    "message": "The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation.", 
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "androidpublisher", 
        "message": "The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation.", 
        "reason": "permissionDenied"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have read and implemented changes recommended in other posts such as

1. added in-app product/subscription before granting permission or linking to service account
2. opened "in-app products/subscription" and performed some updates
3. Verified all *Users and Permissions* through Google Play Console

   - eg. service account is admin user
4. waited over 48 hours to allow Google to propagate all access rights for APIs.

I have also tried calling the API through
https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.subscriptions/get#authorization-scopes
but still no luck (get an error).

If anyone has any suggestions, that would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I am having the same issue. I see a lot of other users having this issue, but I tried everything in the other posts, but no luck.

Comment: Please eidt your question and include the code where you do this **Generate the Refresh Token and the Access Token by sending POST request.**  As service accounts dont have refresh tokens i would love to see how you are managing that.

Comment: As stated in my question, I used the steps listed https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/authorization to generate the refresh token and access token.

Comment: There was a question about this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43536904/google-play-developer-api-the-current-user-has-insufficient-permissions-to-pe

Comment: I have tried all suggestions listed in the above topic, but unfortunately still no luck.

Answer (score 9):

I faced a similar issue, the problem is in the settings we do in google developer project.

Refer to [create-play-service-credentials](https://docs.revenuecat.com/docs/creating-play-service-credentials) for settings. Use the same primary account with which you created your in-app products.

Make sure you remove the previous one.

Link to a Google Developer Project
Your Play Developer account needs to be linked to a Google Developer Project.

**1a. Open the Settings > Developer account menus and select API access**

[image: API-access]

**1b. Select Link to connect your Play account to a Google Developer Project**

[image: choose-project-link]

**1c. Agree to the terms and conditions**

[image: agree-terms-conditions]

**2. Create Service Account**
Next we need to create a service account. This is done from the Google API Console.

**2a. Select Create Service Account**

[image: create-service-account]

**2b. Create Service account key credentials**

[image: service-account]

**2c. Enter details for service account**

[image: enter-service-account-details]

**2d. Download your JSON credential:**
[image: json-credentials]

**3. Grant Access**

**3a. In Play Console, select Grant Access on the newly created service account**

[image: grant-access]

**3b. Grant the following permissions:**

[image: apply-permissions]

**3c.Click Invite User at the bottom and send the invite**

[image: send-invite]

You will be redirected to Users and Permissions where you should see your newly created service account as Active.

Comment: Service accounts no longer respond to api invites.  Have you tested the last part?

Comment: I think you probably won't require that. It would work without that only. In my case I missed 3a and probably something else as well. That's why the second time I did stepwise and it worked.

Comment: so I went through all this again, and created a new service account, but still get the same error :(

Comment: @James Did you even figure out why this guide didn't work? I've also followed it meticulously, and it also closely matches up with the official Android guides on how to verify receipts from Subscriptions. But I'm also not able to request verification, I also just get a "The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation.", despite the fact that my service account has all the permissions it could possibly need. Any ideas?? (I have also tried waiting 24 hours from when the permission was granted)

Comment: Sorry, never got it to work. Crazy complicated process that gives useless error messages.

Answer (score 3):

30 hours later, I found what was wrong with mine, I didn't click the Add app button on the Users and Permissions page after adding the service account.

[image: The invisible add app button]

Answer (score 3):

In case someone else runs into this issue. If your app is still in testing don't forget to add the service account to your testers.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. In my case, I was not using a key file (json one) for the granted service account on Google Play while verifying purchases on the back-end. I replaced the wrong key file with the one of granted service account on Google Play and it's working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

In 2024 I think the options in Google play console got changed. In My case it worked after adding the service account email in "Users and permissions" section of Google Play Console.

Important note: that we need to wait at-least 24hrs after adding the user in Google play console

[image]