# How to fetch the 'benefits' of an in-app product or subscription with Google Play Billing Library?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I'm using the [Google Play Billing Library](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate) version 3 to fetch available in-app products and subscriptions.

After calling `querySkuDetailsAsync` on the `BillingClient` object, I'm correctly getting the `SkuDetails` for each product.

In the Google Play Console, I typed-in some benefits into the "Benefits" field, however, I don't see any methods for getting them.

I'm able to get the name, price, description of the product, but not the benefits.

---

[image: Google Play Console - In app products]

---

**How can I fetch the benefits of an in-app product or subscription?**

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? And was title really the thing you expected it to be?

Comment: I did not find a solution yet

Comment: To bad. I filled a issue on GitHub that the title was not what I expected, but looks like Google is not looking at those issues https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples/issues/495

Comment: 1.5 years and two SDK updates later and these benefits are still nowhere to be found in the result objects that we fetch from the server. Seems like it was a cool idea by the website developers and the API developers didn't get to implementing it

Comment: So starting this summer they implemented a way to get those benefits, but only for REST API, not the `billing` library... Google...
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2023/06/changes-to-google-play-developer-api-june-2023.html
https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/monetization.subscriptions#subscriptionlisting

Answer (score 1):

So as Starwave mentioned in the comment, you can get benefits out of subscription with this api but before that enable Google Play Api from here: ([Google Play Api](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65032139/7254873) )

```
GET https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/{packageName}/subscriptions/{productId}
```

response:

```
    {
  "packageName": "app.test",
  "productId": "month_id",
  "basePlans": [
    ....
  ],
  "listings": [
    {
      "title": "Monthly subscription",
      "benefits": [
        "Lesser price",
        "Another benefit"
      ],
      "languageCode": "en-US"
    }
  ],
  "taxAndComplianceSettings": {
    "eeaWithdrawalRightType": "WITHDRAWAL_RIGHT_SERVICE",
    "taxRateInfoByRegionCode": {
      "US": {
        "eligibleForStreamingServiceTaxRate": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```