# How to get email id or order id to database when user purchases my app from play store

Tags: android

I want to get order id or email id of user when he purchases my app from play store.

I want that when ever user purchases my app, the order id gets stored in my sql database. Next when user signup from my app and enters order id, that order id can be validated with stored order id.

Or if I can get email id used for that purchase then I can store that purchase with that email id.

Thanks

Comment: Refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/34005001

Comment: @Arpanßløødyßadßøy This post talks about inapp purchases. I want orderid when user purchases app from play store

Comment: Did you have a look at the [Playstore Developer API](https://developer.android.com/google/play/developer-api.html)?

Comment: Yes but has code for in-app purchase only

Answer (score 2):

It cannot be done.

You cannot get the order IDs of customer purchases.

Answer (score 1):

**When the application open then in your first activity
you can have this method for checking purchase done or not?**

*This is basic code to understand how to get inapp details, You may need to add security in this by using native or encryption.*

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity{
private IabHelper mIabHelper;
    private void checkPurchase(){
        String base64EncodedPublickey = "Your BASE 64 key";
        if (mIabHelper == null) {
            mIabHelper = new IabHelper(getActivity(), base64EncodedPublickey);
            mIabHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
                    try {
                        if (result.isSuccess()) {
                            mIabHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mQueryFinishedListener);
                        }
                    } catch (IabHelper.IabAsyncInProgressException e) {
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener
                mQueryFinishedListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
            public void onQueryInventoryFinished(final IabResult result, final Inventory inventory) {
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                try {
                    if (result.isFailure()) {
                        return;
                    }
                    if (inventory.hasPurchase("Package name")) {
                        Purchase purchase = inventory.getPurchase("Inapp Package name");
                        if (purchase != null) {
                            String puchaseDetails = gson.toJson(purchase);
                              Log.e(TAG, "Purchase Data : "+puchaseDetails);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    localData = null;
                }
            }
        };
}
```

Comment: Buy I want to check for purchase made from play store directly and not for inapp purchases. For inapp purchases google has api also. But I want purchases from play store

Comment: Play store purchase will be also called as inapp purchase