# Which URL to verify a transaction test Google in-app purchase?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I have a transaction test in-app purchase google success in my device. how to verify it on my serer back-end? or have a url to verify?. thank

Answer (score 1):

It's depends on your server that which back end server you are using.Because there is lib and packages which help you to verify your google payment depending your server.

For example:

If your back end server is `Nodejs` and you want to verify `android` in app then there is a module named `iab_verifier` and for `ios` purchase verification `iap_verifier` named module is available. So it's depends on your back end server.

You can find more detail about it from Google play developer API [here](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/get)

You can also get detailed answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33850864/how-to-verify-purchase-for-android-app-in-server-side-google-play-in-app-billin)

Comment: sorry. my server use Java

Comment: okay, then this link may help you [link](https://medium.com/@infinitesimal_/doing-android-purchase-validation-api-v3-in-java-5c46fc837368)

Comment: Mahesh Bhilavala  .Thank you.