# Flutter in-app-purchase verification with PHP

Tags: php, flutter, in-app-purchase, verification

I have made an app with Flutter and I've added an unlock features option with [in-app-purchase](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase) plugin. All works fine but I want to verify the purchase with a PHP script. I already have a PHP server so I need to use that to verify the purchase. How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: any error you are getting?

Comment: You can use the developer APIs provided by the play store and app store for this by generating tokens. For example, in this answer, it is mentioned how the server-side editing will be for the play store. https://stackoverflow.com/a/34005001/9011129

Comment: do you have solved this?