# Google subscriptions - number of active subscriptions on backend vs Play Console

Tags: android, google-play-console, subscription, in-app-subscription, google-play-developer-api

We are verifying Google subscriptions on backend using requests to:
https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.subscriptions?hl=en
we have also integrated with server notifications, so that we have updated data on all subscriptions.

I started to compare numbers displayed on play.google.com/console to what we have in our app and those are nowhere close. On our backend we see 30% more subscriptions that are marked as active then on Play Console.

1. On Play console I have restricted Subscription data chart to only single day and got number of subscriptions that were active at least for one day within given time window (so 1 day).
2. On our backend I got all subscriptions that had startTimeMillis before (or equal) given day and expiryTimeMillis after (or equal)

The difference was around 30% (Play console shows lower numbers). For all subscriptions I got updated data from purchase.subscriptions api (linked at the top) and confirmed that all of them should be active:

- paymentState=1
- checked date is between start/end date for subscription

According to other stackoverflow answers like:
[How to verify purchase for android app in server side (google play in app billing v3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33850864/how-to-verify-purchase-for-android-app-in-server-side-google-play-in-app-billin/34005001#34005001)

checking expire date should be enough to verify if subscription should be active or not. But Maybe I'm missing something? Or maybe Play Console is not showing what I think I see?